# How to use both Django Auth and DRF Token auth?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am building a Django web app where I want two things:

- Use Django's in-built User model for Django's Admin app usage (store owner)
- Use DRF's Token Auth on a custom User model that I will be naming "Customer" (store customer)

How do I keep both the Authentication systems for the above stated purposes. From what I have read every one asks to override the User model but I don't want to do that. Instead I want to keep both. What strategy should I take up?

PS: It might be me, but I am not able to find any solution for this in DRF's Documentation. If there is please do point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does provide an option for using a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). But you can have one and only one user model.

The process is fairly simple, create your own model inheriting django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser and specify the AUTH_USER_MODEL settings variable. The Django admin works pretty well with the "custom user model" concept. The DRF token model also uses the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL var for its OneToOne relation. So, this is can be a viable solution.

To separate out the user types, you can either use a char field with choices representing the user type or use the existing Django groups mechanism. But, in both cases, you could still only have one user model.

For any specific details, you can have OneToOne relations with different models storing extra info.

Something like this would do,

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from model_utils.choices import Choices   # Useful package
from django.utils.functional import cached_property


class User(AbstractUser):
    USER_TYPES = Choices(
        ("store_owner", "Store Owner"),
        ("customer", "Customer"),
    )
    ...hack...
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPES)
    ...hack...

    @cached_property
    def is_store_owner(self):
        return (
            self.user_type == self.USER_TYPES.store_owner 
            and self.store_owner is not None
        )

    @cached_property
    def is_customer(self):
        return (
            self.user_type == self.USER_TYPES.customer 
            and self.customer is not None
        )


class StoreOwner(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        "yourapp.User", 
        related_name="store_owner",
    )
    # ...extra store owner details...


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        "userapp.User",
        related_name="customer",
    )
    # ...extra customer details...
```